# Using gluLookAt() correctly?

Tags: c, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

I am trying to set the angle of View with `gluLookAt()`

Here I have my code where I tried to set the camera without results

Here the function `displaycone()`:

```
void displayCone(void)
{

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    // clear the drawing buffer.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // clear the identity matrix.
    glLoadIdentity();
    // traslate the draw by z = -4.0
    // Note this when you decrease z like -8.0 the drawing will looks       far , or smaller.
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-4.5);
    // Red color used to draw.
    glColor3f(0.8, 0.2, 0.1);
    // changing in transformation matrix.
    // rotation about X axis
    glRotatef(xRotated,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    // rotation about Y axis
    glRotatef(yRotated,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    // rotation about Z axis
    glRotatef(zRotated,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    // scaling transfomation
    glScalef(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    // built-in (glut library) function , draw you a Cone.

    // move the peak of the cone to the origin
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -height);

    glutSolidCone(base,height,slices,stacks);
    // Flush buffers to screen
    gluLookAt(3,3,3,0,0,-4.5,0,1,0);

    glFlush();
    // sawp buffers called because we are using double buffering
    // glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

With my main:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    //double buffering used to avoid flickering problem in animation
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    // window size
    glutInitWindowSize(400,350);

    // create the window
    glutCreateWindow("Cone Rotating Animation");
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);

    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    //Assign  the function used in events

    glutDisplayFunc(displayCone);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeCone);
    glutIdleFunc(idleCone);
    //Let start glut loop
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

The function `idlecone` instead changes the values of `xRotated`, `yRotated`... and displays the cone. Any ideas?

I am pretty sure I didn't understand the right moment where to use `gluLookAt()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`gluLookAt`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) changes the current matrix, similar to `glTranslatef` or `glRotatef`.
The operation defines a transformation matrix and multiplies the current matrix by the new transformation matrix.

`gluLookAt` has to be called before `glutSolidCone`, e.g.:

```c
void displayCone(void)
{
    // set matrix mode 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    // clear model view matrix
    glLoadIdentity();
    // multiply view matrix to current matrix
    gluLookAt(3,3,3,0,0,-4.5,0,1,0); // <----------------------- add

    // clear the drawing buffer.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // traslate the draw by z = -4.0
    // Note this when you decrease z like -8.0 the drawing will looks far , or smaller.
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-4.5);
    // Red color used to draw.
    glColor3f(0.8, 0.2, 0.1);
    // changing in transformation matrix.
    // rotation about X axis
    glRotatef(xRotated,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    // rotation about Y axis
    glRotatef(yRotated,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    // rotation about Z axis
    glRotatef(zRotated,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    // scaling transfomation
    glScalef(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    // built-in (glut library) function , draw you a Cone.

    // move the peak of the cone to the origin
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -height);

    glutSolidCone(base,height,slices,stacks);
    // Flush buffers to screen
    // gluLookAt(3,3,3,0,0,-4.5,0,1,0); <----------------------- delete

    glFlush();
    // sawp buffers called because we are using double buffering
    // glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: I don't get what I want in this way. Is it possible to change the position of the eye with gluLookAt ? Because with my code I see the cone only from the top and I wanted to set an angle of View of 45 degrees from the soil. @Rabbid76

Comment: @Jatos Waht do you want to achieve? The first 3 parameters of `glLookAt` are the coordinates of the eye (camera) position.

Comment: I tried changing the Parameters into the function but it seems nothing is changing @Rabbid76

Comment: @Jatos The first 3 parameters are the camera position. The parameters 4 to 6 are the target. Note, the camera position has to be set in relation to the target. Possibly `gluLookAt(3, 3, 3-4.5, 0, 0, -4.5, 0, 1, 0);` does what you want. Because of the rotation the changes are difficult to see. Skip the `glRotation`s for debug reasons to investigate the effect of `glLookAt`

Comment: is it also possible to draw X, Y and Z axis after gluLookAt? @Rabbid76

Comment: @Jatos Yes of course. You've to draw the axis in world coordinates, after `gluLookAt`.